# How to `Deref` from `WrapperB{ b: B,... }` to `WrapperA{ a: A,...}` when `B` can `deref` into `A`

Tags: rust

I stumble onto this patter occasionally in Rust and so far I have not found a solution that would not be cumbersome.

Basically, the problem is that I have:

```rust
struct A {...};
struct B { a: A, ...}

impl Deref for B {
    type Target = A;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.a
    }
}
```

I want to wrap `A` and `B`

```rust
struct WrapA { a: A, ... }
impl WrapA { /* a long list of public functions */ }

struct WrapB { b: B, ... }
impl WrapB { /* a long list of public functions */ }
```

Now in the title I wrote that I want to `impl Deref for WrapB { type Target = WrapA; ...}`. I'm quite sure this can't be done, but is there at least any other solution to use the API from `WrapA` when I "only" have `WrapB`?

A solution that comes to my mind is to create `Ref` classes like so:

```rust
struct WrapARef<'a> { a: &'a A, ... }
impl<'a> WrapARef<'a> { /* repeat the long list of functions in WrapA */ }

impl WrapB {
   ...
   fn as_wrap_a<'l>(&'l self) -> WrapARef<'l> {
       WrapARef { a: &self.b, ... }
   }
}
```

But that's very cumbersome, and then I'll also want to do `DerefMut` analogue.

Pictorially, I'm looking for this pattern:

```
    B   ==> wrap ==> WrapB
    ↓                  ↓
  deref                ?
    ↓                  ↓ 
    A   ==> wrap ==> Something with WrapA API
```

Comment: Is `A` the only field of `WrapA`, or at least the only non-ZST field?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman unfortunately no.

Comment: Then unfortunately there is not a lot you can do. You can make `WrapA` generic over `AsRef<A>` and return `WrapA<&A>`, but I'm not sure this is a good idea.

Comment: Hm, the `AsRef` idea sounds interesting. If I understand it correctly, I could create a private `GenericWrapA<Inner : AsRef<A>>` where I would define all the function I would have normally done for `WrapA`  (once) and then make public type aliases for `WrapA` and `WrapARef` .

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: To me, it feels like `Deref` is not quite the trait you are looking for in this situation. `T: Deref<Target = U>` means `T` can be seen as a pointer-like thing that targets `U`. In this case, if `B` is a "pointer" to `A`, there is no reason to believe that something that contains `B` is a "pointer" to something that contains `A`, so you're going to fight against the API.

Comment: @jthulhu yeah, I mentioned in the original post that `Deref` is likely not what I'm looking for. What I'm looking for is something that turns `WrapB` into something that has `WrapA` API. I think the `AsRef` approach that @ChayimFriedman suggested might be a usable option (one with which I can avoid writing `WrapA` API twice).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It [seems to work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=6ddeb806bb4576ed79f2f75817c97d40). If you feel like writing an answer I'm happy to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic `WrapA`, over [`AsRef<A>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) or [`Borrow<A>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html). If you only want to support owned and reference, I recommend `Borrow` since it has a blanket implementation `Borrow<T> for T`, which `AsRef` does not, and this saves you from writing this implementation yourself

Be aware of the disadvantages, though: it may add to compile times and binary size, because you essentially compile `WrapA` twice.

Comment: Thanks, marked as answer. Might be appreciated by others if you also add the code. If you do, free to use the one from the link in the above comment section.